# Is it possible to define some form of relationship between two operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, recreational-mathematics, intuition, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

I am thinking we have transformations and all forms of relationships on sets. But thinking for an abstract algebraic theoretical session, I pondered on whether its possible to transform (or just relate) a single operation to another?

For example

If I have two groups $(G,*)$ and **$(H, \bullet)$** and the isomorphism $$f: G \rightarrow H$$Is it possible to define some form of relationship, say g, such that g focuses on relating "*" and "$\bullet$". If yes, please advise on anyway to do it.

Comment: It seems like the obstacle is that since the elements in $G$ and $H$ are different, attempting to use either operation on the other group might be *gibberish*.  Therefore, the isomorphism property seems the limit of what's possible.  As an example of a set that defines (for example) $+$ and $\times$, then, when $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}, ~(a \times b) \rightarrow (a + a + \cdots + a) ~: ~b~$ terms.

Comment: Since $f(a*b)=f(a)\bullet f(b)$ you can relate $*$ to $\bullet$ as $a*b=f^{-1}(f(a)\bullet f(b))$. In fact, if there is a binary operation $\bullet$ on $Y$ and you have a bijective map $f:X\to Y$ then $a*b:=f^{-1}(f(a)\bullet f(b))$ defines a binary operation on $X$ that makes $f$ into an isomorphism. For instance, taking $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, $\bullet=+$ and $f(x)=x^3$ defines a new addition on $\mathbb{R}$, namely $a*b=\sqrt[3]{a^3+b^3}$.